# Opened file for write but file not showing in project folder (Xcode)

Tags: c, xcode

When writing a program in Xcode I opened 2 files for write ("w") and even opened one of them for read ("r") after. However these files did not show up in the project folder or even in my search results when i searched system.

I am attaching my code and the screen shots of the project folder and the results of my finder search.

```
int main (void)
{
    int Number;
    FILE* Read_File;
    FILE* Write_File;
    
    Write_File = fopen("Test File.txt", "w");
    Read_File = fopen("Test File.txt", "r");
    
    Write_File = fopen("New_File.txt", "w");
    
    fscanf (Read_File, "%d", &Number);
    fprintf(Write_File, "%s", "Test");
    
    printf("Test\n");
    printf("%d", Number);
    puts("");
}
```

[image: Project Folder]

[image: System Search Results]

I did change the search results to "This mac" and enable show hidden files but this did nothing

Comment: You can call `getcwd` in the code to get the path to the current working directory. That's where the files will be created.

Comment: You can also set the working directory in the project settings. In the "Help" menu search for "edit scheme" to find the menu.

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but it seems weird that you open Test File.txt for writing, then immediately for reading.

Comment: If you are opening a file for `"r"` and reading and printing a number that does not appear in the program, how can you not know where it is? You must have put the number in the file yourself. But the posted code can't be right because first you destroy the file you are going to read. However, you haven't checked a *single thing* in the code: not if the files opened, and not if `scanf` was successful. You also didn't close the files, and you didn't `#include <stdio.h>`.

Comment: @WeatherVane, Yes. Sorry about that I should I specified. I opened the stdio.h and another few libraries in my header file and included them in my main.c. as for opening for Read right after Opening for Write, I did this because I initially created a file and put a number in there. Then I tried writing something to the file after opening it for write but that didn't write anything not did it give me any errors. So I deleted the file opening it for read and then for write to see If the file was actually deleted but it read the same number i had put in there even though It shouldnt "exist".

Comment: I am new to C and Xcode so I might make some pretty newbie mistakes to please forgive me. I appreciate any help I can get right now because I am trying to learn

Comment: I really don't get why you begin by destroying "Test File.txt" and then expect to be able read a value from it. You should also verify that each instruction did work. Check that the file opened. Check that `scanf` returns `1`. Also, please *show the program output*, in the question.

Comment: @WeatherVane, I wanted to destroy the file and try open a new one to see if reading a number from it would give me an error or read a garbage value indicating that the file was deleted and a new file was created. Because when i tried writing something to the file (prior to destroying it) it said it wrote it but it never appeared in the file. So i suspected that it was writing it to a file somewhere else and not the file I was actually thinking about. Sorry if these seems very dumb but I am very new to C so forgive me. I will also include outputs next time when I ask a question.

Comment: Look at the date of the file you expected to write to. Or place a test file for reading in the same folder that you want to write to, and see if you are able to open it. It's very unclear what you are trying to do – it reads like a muddle, sorry.

Comment: @user3386109. Thanks this helped alot. The files that it was writing to were located in Xcodes "Derived Data" rather than the actual working directory where my main and header files were. Why i dont know, but thanks this helped me fix my problem

Comment: @WeatherVane, ya i get what you mean sorry, there was probably a much better  way to phrase this question so it wasnt as confusing. I apologize for that. I will work on refining my question and code next time. For now i kinda gets whats going on though after running getcwd(). Thank you for your help though.